# Identifying Windows Server versions

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am making an inventory for software at my workplace, I am having trouble figuring out the various versions of Windows Server OSes.

**Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 Edition Service Pack 2** - Is this Enterprise Edition or does having no specific edition mentioned mean that its Standard Edition?

**Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition (Windows Rights Management Services 1.0) -** - this one doesn't mention the hardware architecture, does it mean that its 32Bit/x86?

Any help or pointers on this are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting this information from? When running the OS or from the label on the installation DVD/CD?

Comment: @iglvzx - I am reading it off the label on the installation DVD/CD. Is there some kind of a convention that if the default version is Standard, Default arch is x86 and the default SP is none?

Answer (score 1):

**Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 Edition Service Pack 2** - Multiple x64 editions are supported with this service pack disc. See [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=6905) for more information.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: It's an answer to part of the question. Question was: "Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 Edition Service Pack 2 - Is this Enterprise Edition or does having no specific edition mentioned mean that its Standard Edition?" in regards to having a bunch of CD/DVDs, but being unsure at to which operating system they are for. My answer clears up the first part.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it by hand, right click **My Computer -> Properties**

It should list the server and specs on the "General" tab, like this:

[image]

If there are a lot of servers I would look into writing a script or using something like Spiceworks to automatically inventory those attributes for you.

Comment: I have a bunch of CD/DVDs from which I am trying to figure out which is which. Some of these are unused, so there is no Physical Server to verify the version from.

Comment: I apparently wasn't aware that you didn't actually have access to the server.  I don't believe know of a way to determine the OS based on the product key so you may just have to boot the installer and check each one individually.